# Internal redirect in Apache VirtualHost configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Accessing the Plex media server requires to access `http://my-ip:32400/web` which isn't very easy for non-techies to remember. I followed [a blog post](http://matt.coneybeare.me/how-to-map-plex-media-server-to-your-home-domain/) I found to simplify this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mediaserver

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:32400/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:32400/

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Plex-Device} ^$
    RewriteRule ^/$ /web/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

I also pointed `mediaserver` on my DNS server to the correct IP. This works in a way. Now I can just type `http://mediaserver` to access the Plex media server. However, this redirects to `http://mediaserver/web`. In the `RewriteRule` there are `R` and `L` flags. I read the documentation for the flags, removed them and added `PT` flag. I also checked [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html) for internal redirecting, where I found the `PT` flag.

So, with the rewrite rule written as `RewriteRule ^/$ /web/$1 [PT]`, I thought it would internally redirect to `/web/` and not show it in the URL. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /web [L]
```

- There is no group capture, so the `$1` was not doing anything
- The `R` is what causes the url to change in the browser. With just the `L`, you have an internal redirect, but the user doesn't see the rewritten url.